# How to properly map array from body returning zero count in asp.net core

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-core, razor

I have a jquery in the razor page collecting checked ids and passing them to the controller in asp.net core application.

The jquery is working fine but I always get count zero in the controllers.

I have tried some of the examples here. I also use [frombody] this did even hit the controller

```
  $('#Delete').click(function () {
            var fav = [];
            $.each($("input[name='ID']:checked"), function () {
                fav.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Loan/Delete",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(fav),
                success: function (result) {
                }
            })

        });
```

controller
In the controllers, the ids count is zero

```
   public void DeleteStatementsRoles(ICollection<Products> ids){}
```

I guess I am doing something wrong

Comment: When sending only json you need to set appropriate contentType

Comment: I added the ```  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",``` didnt work either

Comment: Ohh...you have `favorite` in data but array is named `fav`. Make sure to check errors in browser dev tools console, that would throw one there

Comment: I have corrected now I can get array in the console ```Array(2)
0: "1"
1: "2" ``` but still not getting to the controller

Comment: Could you please share your Product model?And how did you design your `favorite` variable.

Comment: I'm not an asp dev so not sure about that code shown. However narrow down what happens with request also in browser dev tools network. What is status, is what is sent what is expected, what is returned etc?

Comment: @Rena its just a simple POCO object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form>
    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
   <input type="button" id="Delete" value="delete" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $('#Delete').click(function () {
            var fav = [];
            $.each($("input[name='ID']:checked"), function () {
                var obj = {};              //change here...
                obj.Id = $(this).val()
                fav.push(obj);
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/Delete",
                contentType: "application/json",  //add this..
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(fav),
                success: function (result) {
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Delete([FromBody] ICollection<Products> ids) 
    { 
         //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Another situation**:For I'm not sure what is your model,here is also a working demo which model contains a list.

Model:

```
public class Products
{
    public List<int> Id { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form>
    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
   <input type="button" id="Delete" value="delete" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $('#Delete').click(function () {
            var fav = [];
            $.each($("input[name='ID']:checked"), function () {
                fav.push($(this).val());
            });
            var favarite = [];     //add...
            favarite.push({ id: fav });
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/Delete",
                contentType: "application/json",   //add this...
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(favarite),
                success: function (result) {
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: My model is just like the first example. once I put ```[FromBody]```  then it doesn't hit the controller. if I remove ```[FromBody]``` then hits controller will zero count

Comment: Be sure you have added `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax.

Comment: I suggest that you could share your model and the whole razor view with jQuery.This would help you resolve issue more quickly.

Comment: The razor is huge, Another thing is I tried ```IFormCollection``` and I got ``` "[{\"Id\":\"1\"},{\"Id\":\"2\"}]" ``` Maybe I will have to share it eventually

Comment: I think you need copy my whole code to your project.Maybe you miss something in your project.Make sure adding `contentType: "application/json"` in your ajax and adding `[FromBody]` in your action.

Comment: Why did you add two click event for button `DeleteStatementsRoles`?(`$('#DeleteStatementsRoles').click()` and `$("#DeleteStatementsRoles").on("click", function () {})`).You could only use one click event.And I even can't see checkbox with name ID in your razor view.Also I see you comment the `contentType: "application/json"`.Do not comment it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220950/discussion-between-techstack-and-rena).